# How to get a POST request values' list in Django?

Tags: python, django, post, django-views, django-templates

Suppose the parameter I want to pass is called `printdata`, and `printdata=['a', 'b', 'c']`.

I use `"input type="hidden" name="alist" value={{printdata}}>"` to pass
the parameter. However, when I try to retrieve the parameter in
views.py using the following code:

```
params = request.POST
```

`params["alist"]` is equal to `['a',` instead of `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I suspect that
django identifies the end of a parameters using `,`.

Do you have any suggestions or any other methods to pass the parameter?

Answer (score 8):

Use multiple hidden fields, one for each value, in your HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="3" />
```

On the server side, use `request.POST.getlist` to read all the values as a list:

```
alist = request.POST.getlist('alist')
# 'alist' now contains ['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put quotation marks around the list string in your HTML. ie:

```
<input type="hidden" name="alist" value="{{printdata}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
request.POST.getlist('alist')
```

to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = request.POST.get('alist')
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you submit the `POST` request values' list in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple" /></br>
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="orange" /></br>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values' list in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below. *According to my experiments, you cannot properly get the `POST` request values' list in Django Templates and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106783/how-to-get-a-get-request-values-list-in-django/77129778#77129778) explains how to get a `GET` request values' list in Django and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/how-to-get-post-request-values-in-django/77136495#77136495) explains how to get `POST` request values in Django:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    print(request.POST.getlist('fruits')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(request.POST.getlist('meat')) # []
    print(request.POST.getlist('meat', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.POST._getlist('fruits')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(request.POST._getlist('meat')) # []
    print(request.POST._getlist('meat', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(list(request.POST.lists())) # [('csrfmiddlewaretoken', ['OE3hidxt0awKjRFXxUddvT6u0cRfhdMnsVGpsYWAhd0hMUabpY3vFp6xkCub9Jlb']), ('fruits', ['apple', 'orange'])]
    print(dict(request.POST)) # {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['OE3hidxt0awKjRFXxUddvT6u0cRfhdMnsVGpsYWAhd0hMUabpY3vFp6xkCub9Jlb'], 'fruits': ['apple', 'orange']}

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

In addition, if you submit the `POST` request values' list in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
<form action="{% url 'my_app1:test' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="fruits" value="apple,orange" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values' list in `my_app1/views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):

    print(request.POST['fruits'].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(request.POST.getlist('fruits')[0].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(request.POST._getlist('fruits')[0].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(list(request.POST.values())[1].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(list(request.POST.items())[1][1].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(list(request.POST.lists())[1][1][0].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(request.POST.dict()['fruits'].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']
    print(dict(request.POST)['fruits'][0].split(',')) # ['apple', 'orange']

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then, you can get the `POST` request values' list in `test.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "test.html" #}

{{ request.POST.fruits }} {# apple,orange #}
{{ request.POST.dict }} {# {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'y2yGzMMJq2kVXGLUZ68JJxpNbYpFxZyRcjbOJxbQH5OsqJg8RaY1T3pQvo2Bpv7F', 'fruits': 'apple,orange'} #}
```