# Filter objects with Rest Framework Django API

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have a model `Person` in Django

```py
class Language(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Person(models.Model):
    PersonId= models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    Countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    Languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)
```

each person can have (visit) many countries and have (speak) many languages.

I want to create an API that I will send to the endpoint list of few `languages` and `countries`, and will return for me the people, which has at their list at least one of the language and one country from the lists that I sent.

For example I have

`Person(1,['Portugal', 'Spain'],['portugues','spanish'])` ,

`Person(2, ['Portugal', 'Germany'],['portugues','russian'])`,

`Person(3,['France', 'Spain'],['spanish', 'french'])`

I sent data

```
{
   Countries: ['Portugal', 'France'],
   Languages: ['russian', 'french']
}
```

so in this case it returns `Person2` and `Person3`.
My PersonView with Authentication

```
class PeopleListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Blog.objects.filter(UserId=self.request.user)
```

Is there any way to do this? I would not like to search by url but send data in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it would look like if you were to test the answer below using requests. The simplicity and usage is why I think you can skip the requirement of not wanting the url to contain filter information.

```py
import requests

requests.get(
    f'http://{site}', 
    params={'Countries': ['Portugal', 'France'], 'Languages': ['russian', 'french']}
).json()
```

The requests library [allows for parameters to be sent as a list in a dictionary](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

The `PeopleListView` needs to have the queryset updated based on the values sent.

```py
class PeopleListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
    """Returns a list of of People that match the critera"""
        # get query parameters
        countries = self.request.GET.getlist('Countries', None)
        languages = self.request.GET.getlist('languages', None)

        # return the filter set based on parameters sent
        if countries is not None and languages is not None:
            return Person.objects.filter(countries__name__in=countries).filter(languages__name__in=languages)
        elif countries is not None and languages is None:
            return Person.objects.filter(countries__name__in=countries)
        elif countries is None and languages is not None:
            return Person.objects.filter(languages__name__in=languages)
        else:
            return Person.objects.all()  # returns everyone if no filters set
```

This uses the [The documentation on filtering with Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url) to change the query set based on the parameters sent.

The `if.. elif... elif... else` block uses [The documentation on filtering in Django's orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Comment: Hey, thank you or a response. I did test your response with POSTMAN, and  your answer helped me a lot, but there are some issues. Firt one is that I cannot send array of options, but each option seperated like this `?Countries=France&Countries=Portugal&Languages=russian` and then in django convert them to lists  `countries = self.request.GET.getlist('Countries')`. (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106783/django-get-query-parameter-list`) You can update your answer so I can accept as correct one.

Comment: makes sense! I'm glad you were able to get it to work! I just updated the answer. Is it what you were expecting it should be?

Comment: Only the params in your request do not match the one I wrote - they cannot be arrays

Comment: if you visit the site from your web browser you'll need to separate the parameters just like you have `?Countries=France&Countries=Portugal..etc..`. If you use the `requests` library you can send everything over as a dictionary with embeded lists according to the documentation. I think that is what you are referring too. I've updated my answer to include more information on the documentation from `requests`. That first part is more of a reference for how to interact with the view if it helps I can remove it all together.